# Powershell script is not adding node in .csproj file

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, powershell, csproj

I am writing a powershell script to automate some of the boilerplate setup when initiating a .NET Core Blazor application, and for some reason it is not properly updating the `.csproj` file. What I would like to do is add a new node to the root of the file like so:

```
<Project Sdk="...">
  ...
  ... 
  ... 
  <Target Name="Tailwind" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Exec Command="npm run input:build" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The script I am using works when I'm in a test environment using a mocked `.csproj` file:

```
# edit csproj as xml to include npm build scripts
$dir = Split-Path -Path (Get-Location) -Leaf
Write-Host "Adding build directives to "$dir".csproj . . .";
$xml = [XML] (Get-Content $dir".csproj");
$target = $xml.CreateElement("Target");
$target.SetAttribute("Name", "Tailwind");
$target.SetAttribute("BeforeTargets", "Build");
$cmd = $xml.CreateElement("Exec");
$cmd.SetAttribute("Command", "npm run input:build");
$xml.DocumentElement.AppendChild($target);
$target.AppendChild($cmd);
$xml.Save($dir+".csproj");
Write-Host ". . . done.";
```

The rest of the script is running perfectly, and everything seems to be PATH'd correctly. And like I said, the script runs fine in test. Is there a reason that a powershell automation script wouldn't be able to append a node to an existing `.csproj` file in a .NET project?

You'll have to excuse if my powershell looks heinous, as I am very new to it.

Comment: Perhaps it's being saved to a different path than you're expecting... Try `$xml.Save("${PWD}\${dir}.csproj")`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Aha, that's it! Interesting that using relative paths worked fine in a test directory. I guess I should be more explicit about paths in the future. Thank you so much for your response, everything is working perfectly now. I'd give you some feel-good internet points if I could.

Comment: Great to hear! I've linked to a duplicate post that explains why you might see this behavior when passing relative paths to .NET base class libraries (TL;DR: `powershell.exe` doesn't update it's process environment with the new location when you use `cd`/`Set-Location`)

Answer (score 0):

Mathias nailed it, the script required a full path to update and save the `.csproj` file in the root of the project directory.